# Intellij KeyMapping is acting weird

Tags: keyboard, macos, java

I am new to mac so apologies if i am asking a stupid question. I just installed Intellij idea on Mac OS El Capitan and it is acting weird. *This issue is only in Intellij so i am assuming that perhaps i have messed up with some key mapping ??*

For example, Whenever I double click on a text, it selects (as expected) but then moving a cursor acts as if i am holding shift while moving the text and hence it selects everything. To undo this behaviors, I have to do a single click somewhere before i can move cursor.

Also, pressing Shift + Arrow keys (left/right) doesn't select the text, rather it jumps from one word to another. I can only select text from keyboard in intellij with `Options + Shift + Left/Right Arrow` or `CTRL + Shift + Left/Right Arrow`.

What i have done ? I am using eclipse keymapping though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A little digging solved the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639578/intellij-double-click-on-word-issue). In short, I installed **ideaVim** plugin. All I had to do is to disable it.